# Python Mutiprocessing.pool passing row of touple

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a code below that makes a mysql call to get a list of reports I need to request.  It then calls another function "call_report" to request the reports.  The call_report function is low in CPU and mostly waits for a report to be returned.  I want to to run multiple instances of the for loop at the same time but cant figure out how to implement pool where it iterates over the rows in reports_to_run.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_rpt_log")
reports_to_run = cursor.fetchall() 

for row in reports_to_run :
    user=(row[0])
    report=(row[1])
    run_interval=(row[3])

   call_report(report, user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general trick to using `Pool` is to create a wrapper function that takes the input as you have it, transforms it into the input the real function wants, and calls it. Like this:

```
def report_on_row(row):
    user = row[0]
    report = row[1]
    run_internal= row[3]
    return call_report(report, user)
```

And now, you can just use `map` to call this wrapper function on each row:

```
pool.map(report_on_row, reports_to_run)
```